# Find combinations of number to sum up to a number

Tags: java, algorithm, breadth-first-search

I have a problem where I should find the combinations of 5l, 10l, and 15l buckets to fill a reservoir. For example if the reservoir is 30l the combination should be 15l and 15l (this is the best situation, when we use as much bigger buckets as we can).

I had a look on backtracking but not luck so far. The algorithm should be in Java.

Comment: Please post what you have tried till now

Comment: cant say I have done much... I have been trying to work around http://www.programcreek.com/2014/04/leetcode-combination-sum-ii-java/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classic coin change problem which is NP. But there are dynamic programming approaches for solving it for limited size of the problems. For more information:
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-7-coin-change/
http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Coin_Change
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem

Comment: thanks a lot... this is what i needed

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to write the code for you but this should give you a good idea.

Check if the largest (15L) is less than the reservoir. If it is, reduce the reservoir by that amount and make a note that 1 x 15L has been selected. Repeat this using smaller and smaller buckets until you have nothing left (or a remainder).